# servicereference.getBundle() - No such method error

Tags: java, tomcat, osgi, reportviewer

I'm having a trouble trying to make a report viewer on a Tomcat Server using some report viewer tools. When I start my aplication on tomcat, I get this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.actuate.birt.report.viewer.Activator.getBundle()Lorg/osgi/framework/Bundle;
>   at
>   com.actuate.birt.report.viewer.ContextInitListener.contextInitialized(ContextInitListener.java:75)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1897)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: I am not seeing ServiceReference anywhere in the stacktrace, so I am not sure why the title mentions ServiceReference?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I had copy and paste the title of the error, anyway, any help with it?